# Date Range Based on Today

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will be called by an automated report on the 1st, 8th, 15th, and 22nd of each month.

Below I have the code I am currently trying to use however I keep getting the error `Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.` on the line for @StartDate if ran on the 1st. However I have tried commenting out that section and I just get the same error but then for the next @StartDate.

I need @StartDate and @EndDate to be able to change based on which day of the month the report is currently being ran.

- On the 1st it would need to be ran from the 21st of the
  previous month to the end of the previous month.
- On the  8th it would need to be  1st of the current month to the  7th.
- On the 15th it would need to be  8th of the current month to the 14th.
- On the 22nd it would need to be 15th of the current month to the 21st.

  ```
  Declare @RunDate    date
  Declare @StartDate Date
  Declare @EndDate    Date

  Set  @RunDate = '3/1/2017'

  If (Day(@RunDate) = 1)
  Begin

  Set @StartDate  = Convert(Date,(Month(DATEADD(d,-1,@Rundate)) + '/21/' + Case When Month(@Rundate) = '1' Then Year(@RunDate) Else Year(DATEADD(yy,-1,@Rundate)) End),101)
  Set @EndDate    = Convert(date,DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@Rundate),0))),101)

  End
  Else
  IF (Day(@RunDate) = 8)
  Begin

  Set @StartDate  = Convert(Date,(Month(@Rundate) + '/1/' + Year(@RunDate)),101)
  Set @EndDate    = Convert(Date,(Month(@Rundate) + '/7/' + Year(@RunDate)),101)

  End
  Else
  If (Day(@Rundate) = 15)
  Begin

  Set @StartDate  = Convert(Date,(Month(@Rundate) + '/8/' + Year(@RunDate)),101)
  Set @EndDate    = Convert(Date,(Month(@Rundate) + '/14/' + Year(@RunDate)),101)

  End
  Else
  If (Day(@Rundate) = 22)
  Begin

  Set @StartDate  = Convert(Date,(Month(@Rundate) + '/15/' + Year(@RunDate)),101)
  Set @EndDate    = Convert(Date,(Month(@Rundate) + '/21/' + Year(@RunDate)),101)

  End
  ```

I am using SQL Server 2012 back end with SSMS 2016 front end. If that helps.

Comment: I have tried fixing the code tags but ended up removing them and I am unable to add them back for some reason if someone can help me that would be great.

Comment: @Sparrow and hadiThank you Sirs/Madams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify all of that down to:

```
Declare @RunDate date, @StartDate date, @EndDate date;
Set  @RunDate = '20170301';
If (Day(@RunDate) = 1)
Begin;
Set @StartDate = dateadd(day,20,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @RunDate)-1, 0)) 
Set @EndDate   = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @RunDate), 0)) 
End;
Else
If (Day(@RunDate) in (8,15,22))
Begin;
Set @StartDate = dateadd(day,Day(@RunDate)-8,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @RunDate), 0))
Set @EndDate   = dateadd(day,Day(@RunDate)-2,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @RunDate), 0))
End;
```

---

Alternative using `case`, but doesn't verify for the `day()` in `8,15,22`:

```
Declare @RunDate date, @StartDate date, @EndDate date;
Set  @RunDate = '20170328';

set @StartDate = case day(@RunDate)
    when 1 then dateadd(day,20,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @RunDate)-1, 0)) 
    else dateadd(day,Day(@RunDate)-8,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @RunDate), 0))
    end;

set @EndDate = case day(@RunDate)
    when 1 then dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @RunDate), 0)) 
    else dateadd(day,Day(@RunDate)-2,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @RunDate), 0))
    end;
```

rextester demo of both: http://rextester.com/CCUFI85069

Comment: Perfect answer thank you @SqlZim. You have been a wondrous help these last few days.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to set the dates like this...

```
SET @StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, 
    CONCAT(MONTH(DATEADD(d, -1, @Rundate)),
    '/21/',
     IIF(MONTH(@Rundate) = '1', YEAR(@RunDate), YEAR(DATEADD(yy,  -1, @Rundate)))) , 101)
```

The full code will look like this...

```
Declare @RunDate    date
Declare @StartDate Date
Declare @EndDate    Date

Set  @RunDate = '3/1/2017'

If (Day(@RunDate) = 1)
Begin

Set @StartDate  = CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(MONTH(DATEADD(d, -1, @Rundate)), '/21/',IIF(MONTH(@Rundate) = '1', YEAR(@RunDate), YEAR(DATEADD(yy,  -1, @Rundate)))) , 101)
Set @EndDate    = Convert(date,DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@Rundate),0))),101)

End
Else
IF (Day(@RunDate) = 8)
Begin

Set @StartDate  = Convert(Date, CONCAT(Month(@Rundate) , '/1/' , Year(@RunDate)) ,101)
Set @EndDate    = Convert(Date, CONCAT(Month(@Rundate) , '/7/' , Year(@RunDate)) ,101)

End
Else
If (Day(@Rundate) = 15)
Begin

Set @StartDate  = Convert(Date, CONCAT(Month(@Rundate) , '/8/' , Year(@RunDate)) ,101)
Set @EndDate    = Convert(Date, CONCAT(Month(@Rundate) , '/14/' , Year(@RunDate)) ,101)

End
Else
If (Day(@Rundate) = 22)
Begin

Set @StartDate  = Convert(Date, CONCAT(Month(@Rundate) , '/15/' , Year(@RunDate)) ,101)
Set @EndDate    = Convert(Date, CONCAT(Month(@Rundate) , '/21/' , Year(@RunDate)) ,101)

END

SELECT @StartDate, @EndDate
```

You could even hide the repetitive code and create a simple function...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDateBasedOnStringNumber] (@num NVARCHAR(20), @RunDate DATE)
RETURNS DATE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @retDate DATE
  SELECT  @retDate = Convert(Date, CONCAT(Month(@RunDate) , @num , Year(@RunDate)) ,101)

  RETURN @retDate ;
END;
```

and then use this pattern instead...

```
SELECT @StartDate = dbo.GetDateBasedOnStringNumber('/1/', @RunDate)
SELECT @EndDate = dbo.GetDateBasedOnStringNumber('/7/', @RunDate)
```

Comment: I have not had any issues with that part of the code in fact I was able to run it and get it run generic "Hello World" style code for each of the different dates needed. It is the portion where I am setting '@StartDate' and '@EndDate' that it is giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to add `integer` and `varchar` values together. Using this line as an example:

```
Set @StartDate  = Convert(Date,(Month(DATEADD(d,-1,@Rundate)) + '/21/' + Case When Month(@Rundate) = '1' Then Year(@RunDate) Else Year(DATEADD(yy,-1,@Rundate)) End),101)
```

If you break down the parts of your calculation you have the month `integer` value, a day `varchar` value and a year `integer` value. If you try to concatenate these you get the error message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '/21/' to data type int.

You could cast the `integer` values to `varchar` and it would work.

It is recommended to use the built-in `date` functions than using concatenation so you could achieve the same result like so:

```
DECLARE
    @RunDate DATE = '20170101'
,   @StartDate DATE
,   @EndDate DATE

IF DATEPART(DAY, @RunDate) = 1
    SELECT
        @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1, @RunDate)) - 20), @RunDate)
    ,   @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @RunDate)

SELECT
    @StartDate
,   @EndDate
```